# How to import certification correctly in HttpsURLConnection?

Tags: java, ssl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

I use HttpsURLConnection to send request to a server.
At first time, I use a simple way to pass the certificate validation in Java https connections and It works.
(according to the website:
http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/07/16/disable-certificate-validation-in-java-ssl-connections/)

But now, I got an `.pem` file and I need to import it to my JVM.
I tried to import the `.pem` file to my JVM by `keytool -import -file E:\server.pem -alias SERVER -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts"`, but I got an error `java.lang.Exception: not X.509`.

Therefore, I use openssl to transfer the `.pem` to `.der`. Then I imported the `.der` to my JVM by `keytool -import -file E:\server.der -alias SERVER -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts"`.

But when I executed the code without passing the certificate validation, it have an error about `"javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: ...: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException:"`

How can I solve it? Is the error caused by transfering `.pem` to `.der` by myself? Should the server have to use `.der`, too?

Thanks!

**Pass the certificate validation**

```
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
ctx.init(new KeyManager[0], new TrustManager[] {new DefaultTrustManager()}, new SecureRandom());
SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);

// HttpsURLConnection
URL url = new URL(newUrl);
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

connection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
        return true;
    }
});

connection.connect();
BufferedReader reader = null;
String json;

// read the output from the server
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
json = reader.readLine();
connection.disconnect();
```

**Import the certificate**

Could I remove some code such as `SSLContext...` after importing the certification?

```
// HttpsURLConnection
URL url = new URL(newUrl);
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

connection.connect();
BufferedReader reader = null;
String json;

// read the output from the server
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
json = reader.readLine();
connection.disconnect();
```

**Part of server.pem**

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICdwIBADANBgkqhk
....
....
4QOYP5BR7kze/gY=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICSjCCAbOgAwIBAgIJAL9cT+
....
....
bfnoA/x+53HmG0w6fu
x8HXcTCrgsgnYwoMl9A=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 0):

If your server has a self signed certificate and you want to ignore check on the certificate validation, you can you [this code (ignoring-self-signed-certificates-in-java)](https://www.obsidianscheduler.com/blog/ignoring-self-signed-certificates-in-java/) :). Worked perfectly for me.